# What is this houseplant with waxy rounded leaves and a tall straight flower spike?

Tags: identification, houseplants

Can anybody help me identify this plant from the picture posted? It has waxy rounded leaves and is very easy to look after. From the picture you'll see it is flowering in late Summer / Autumn UK.

[image]

Comment: If it's a clivia it will have a brightly coloured flower tending towards oranges/reds/yellows and a large bulb at the base. The stem and leaves remind me of an ornamental onion.  Is there any scent to the leaves or flower?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I started looking around clivia and I found the Haemanthus. It's definately one of those (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haemanthus)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to revive an old post, but:

It's **not** a clivia, it's a Heamanthus albiflos (elephant's ear / paintbrush plant). Close relative from the Amaryllis family, but not the same.
Main differences: Clivias have clusters of bell-shaped blossoms, usually orage(-ish), the leaves are thinner, longer and often darker. 
OP found the correct answer himself.

(Your specimen might appreciate a bit more light, if possible, as it appears a bit lanky.)